# reactjs / flux: execute actions (ajax) in order

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, flux

I have flux actions that are simply AJAX calls that update the store with data on success.

In my component I have a function that uses these actions:

```
// Insert new event
ReactActions.submitNewEvent(data)
// Insert new exceptions 
ReactActions.submitNewExceptions(exception_objects)

// Merge
ReactActions.merge(data, exception_objects)
```

I would like to **execute the first two action** completely (meaning a 200 success response from the ajax method) **before the third action is executed**.

What is the best way to do this in a Flux-like architecture? Should I be opting for promises? Could you present an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, promises are a good approach to solve problems like this.

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will help you with synchronizing the last call with the previous two. Make sure that both `submitNewEvent()` and `submitNewExceptions()` return a promise that is resolved when the AJAX calls are completed:

```
Promise.all([
    ReactActions.submitNewEvent(data),
    ReactActions.submitNewExceptions(exception_objects)
]).then(function() {
    ReactActions.merge(data, exception_objects)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. So does my Action's ajax need to be wrapped with `Promise.resolve()` when its returned?

Comment: Check out the [MDN article about Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). They give some pretty good examples on how to implement them.